# Does Microsoft Power BI Designer support SQL Server 2000 database as data source?

Tags: sql-server, datasource, designer, powerbi, msbi

I am trying to pull in the data from my SQL Server 2000 database (I know, we are very old) into MS Power BI Designer Preview for some report/analysis.

However, I keep getting following error that encryption is not supported. What the heck is that..! I am using SSMS 2012 client tool to access the 2000 database with the same credentials & it works just fine.

Can someone please explain why this error comes up & is there any way to work around this....?

I want to pull in SQL Server 2000 database data in MS Power BI Designer & create reports.

This is the error

> DataSource.Error: Microsoft SQL: The instance of SQL Server you attempted to connect to does not support encryption.
>
> Details:
>   DataSourceKind=SQL
>   DataSourcePath=4_Part_Server_Address;DatabaseName
>
> Message=The instance of SQL Server you attempted to connect to does not support encryption.
>   Number=20
>   Class=20

I also tried to put the screenshot, but it does not let me put the image saying I need at least 10 points to put the images...!!!!!  :(

Comment: I dont believe that Power BI Designer support SQL Server 2000, since Power Query starts support in SQL Server 2008 and Power BI Designer is basically using Power Query tools, and technology under the hood.

Comment: You can always upload your screenshot to a free image hoster, like tinypic.com, and post a link to them here .....

Comment: Power BI Designer supports ODBC.  Did you try that?

Answer (score 0):

Using ODBC worked for me.

On the **Home** ribbon Click **Get Data** and choose **Other...**

Select **ODBC** from the list of data sources

Enter a connection string. For my local SQL Server 2014 express database I used this:

```
database=MyDatabaseName;driver={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};server=(localdb)\ProjectsV12
```

Answer (score 0):

We had the same issue when we disabled TLS 1.0 and TLS 1.1 on the web server - TLS 1.2 was only enabled. When we re-enabled TLS 1.0 and TLS 1.1 it worked fine.

Turns out the client needs to be updated to support TLS 1.2:
[TLS 1.2 Client Support](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlreleaseservices/tls-1-2-support-for-sql-server-2008-2008-r2-2012-and-2014/)

Answer (score 0):

OLEDB connection worked for me - even had a great "Build" option to assist in building the connection string.